# Can anyone assist on this for loop error?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm curious as to why the for loop in my code gives me the error 'unexpected token', maybe a syntax error? It might be obvious but I'm not seeing it. I would appreciate it if it could be pointed out. Thanks :)

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
  let arr_length = arr[0].length;
  let leftSum = 0;
  let rightSum = 0;

  for(let i = 0; j = arr_length - 1; i < arr_length; i++, j--){
    leftSum += arr[i][i];
    rightSum += arr[i][j];
  }
    let difference = leftSum - rightSum

    return Math.abs(difference);
}
```

Comment: The second part should have the condition, whereas you have separated with a ; instead of , for j. After i=0 use , instead of ;

Comment: Consider adding appropriate tags so that your question is visible to the people who can answer your question. for example add a tag of the language you are using for this program.

Comment: Pat thank you so much that was my only issue. :) And sorry it was my first post, I'll definitely keep that in mind!

Comment: Not related to your problem but this looks off: `let arr_length = arr[0].length;`. Perhaps you meant `let arr_length = arr.length;` (without the indexing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop has a semi-colon in the initialization,

```
for(let i = 0; j = arr_length - 1; i < arr_length; i++, j--){

//should be

for(let i = 0, j = arr_length - 1; i < arr_length; i++, j--){
```

Just as an FYI, your browser has a web inspector that highlights the issue (on a Mac click COMMAND+OPTION+J, on windows it's CMD+SHIFT+J.

Clicking on the error message "unexpected token" shows the exact place in the code the error occurred on.